# Is it possible to share data between users in a Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, uwp, local-storage

I'm pretty sure that I know the answer to this question (A big fat NO), but is it possible to share downloaded data between the *same application* but multiple users (Windows login, not Microsoft Store users) in a Windows Runtime environment?  The local data folder is relative to each login user, so this seems impossible at first glance.  It would be a huge waste for each user to have to download all of the content for the application since it is between 700MB - 1GB of content per app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This accepted answer is outdated.  It is now possible to share data between users of a given app in Windows 10, by changing a setting in Group Policy Editor.  The path in GP Editor (gpedit.msc) is:

\ Local Computer Policy \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ App Package Deployment \ "Allow a Windows app to share application data between users".

Set to "Enabled", and an app can share its data across users.

Once enabled, in UWP apps, the path given by Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder.Path is available for sharing data across users.  When not enabled, the path returned by this is Null.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't been up to date with this since I left my previous job a couple years ago, but this might come in handy at some point!

Answer (score 2):

You can only share between accounts which share a Windows Store account and even then the app data is still installed for each account.  http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-tip-share-apps-between-multiple-accounts

Comment: That's what I thought, so it looks like the answer is no.  Well, we have a plan B for just performing login logic inside the app instead so this isn't the end of the world.

Comment: This is an oversight by Microsoft. I want to run apps that my kids run and see the status of the app they are using while on my own desktop. If it be a game, educational app or creative tools. By having access to their app + data I can help them out a little, leave notes and edits for guidance..